# Flex Bindsetter on XML object tag?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, data-binding, flex4

I've got a XML object that is shared by some components. Is it possible to set a BindSetter to a specific tag and call a function if that property changes?

I've tried it, but the BindSetter call doesn't seem to accept XML tag names.

When simply using [Bindable] and using the the tag name in MXML (i.e. label text="{myXMLObject.tagName}") this works fine, so I figure this has to work in pure AS as well, I just haven't figured out how.

Any hints?

Based on the comments/answer, here is a very basic example of my code/usage.

Two components in a Flex app, both inherit the same XML object;

```
[Bindable] public var sharedData:XML;
```

Then in the creationComplete handler of every component, I call the `BindSetter`;

```
BindingUtils.bindSetter(sharedDataChange, sharedData, "tagName");
```

`sharedDataChange` doesn't do anything at this point, just tracing that the function has been called.

I've then got a Label that displays the value of `sharedData.tagName`, a textInput and a button that sets `sharedData.tagName = textInput.text`.
Using MXML binding (`{label.text = sharedData.tagName}`) this works fine. 
But as I said, the BindSetter function doesn't seem to detect the changes.

Comment: maybe someone else can explain directly how to do this to you but you may want to look at just doing a -keep to get the generated actionscript then use some sort of diff viewer to see the difference between two simple Flex apps with the only difference being one of the xml type bindings you're looking for.  Also you should post some code.

Comment: Can you post, how did you write `bindSetter` for `myXMLObject.tagName`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `label text="{myXMLObject.tagName}"` works for you, then

```
 BindingUtils.bindSetter(function(value:*):void{
     //Do something
 }, this, ["myXMLObject","tagName"]);
```

should work as well, but `myXMLObject` must be '`public`'.

There is no difference for [BindingUtils](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/binding/utils/BindingUtils.html) whether it is working with XML or with some other object. If object is specified as `[Bindable]`, then `BindingUtils` will work with it correctly.

**UPDATE:** There is a big difference between

```
BindingUtils.bindSetter(sharedDataChange, sharedData, "tagName");
```

and

```
BindingUtils.bindSetter(sharedDataChange, this, ["sharedData", "tagName"]);
```

If you will write something '`shareData = ...`' , the `setter` of first expression will not be called,but for the second one, it will be.

Comment: That's what I thought, but unfortunately the BindSetter function doesn't get dispatched. My code is basically identical to yours, I added it to my fist post though.

Comment: Checked it, applied it to my code, doesn't work. ;) Using general AS objects (not XML) the BindSetter always worked fine for me. It's just this bloody XML I can't wrap my head around.